# Unexpected method call order in Python multiple inheritance

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance

I have a child class named `USA` and it has two parent classes, `A` and `B`.
Both parents have a method named `change_to_4` and in `B.__init__` I call the method, but instead of using the method that I defined in `B` it uses the `A` definition of the `change_to_4` method.

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.a = 1
        super().__init__()

    def change_to_4(self):
        self.x = 4


class B:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.b = 2
        self.change_to_4()
        super().__init__()

    def change_to_4(self):
        self.b = 4


class USA(A, B):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()


print(f"A vars = {vars(A())}")
print(f"B vars = {vars(B())}")
print(f"USA vars = {vars(USA())}")

print(f"USA mro -> {USA.__mro__}")
```

I expect something like this:

```
A vars = {'a': 1}
B vars = {'b': 4}
USA vars = {'a': 1, 'b': 4}
USA mro -> (<class '__main__.USA'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class 'object'>)
```

But the output is

```
A vars = {'a': 1}
B vars = {'b': 4}
USA vars = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'x': 4}
USA mro -> (<class '__main__.USA'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class 'object'>)
```

Comment: Add a `print(self)` in B's `__init__.py`; it might clear things up a bit (hint: self is perhaps not what you think it is).

Comment: @9769953 `self` of the `USA` was `<__main__.USA object at 0x7f94bf6c79a0>` I expected it to be different from B, but my main issue is I expect when I call USA its attributes being made from its parent and be exactly them, but this is not the case.

Comment: @blhsing yes exactly, I didn't call the `A.change_to_4` at all but in the result i see `'x':4`
that is what `A.change_to_4` does despite never calling it.

Comment: Oops my bad for misreading your code.

Comment: @mkrieger1 oh I wrote it wrong, I meant
"but instead of using the method that I defined in `B` it uses the `A` definition of the `change_to_4" method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the interpreter looks up an attribute of an instance, in this case `self.change_to_4` on an instance of `USA`, it first tries to find `'change_to_4'` in `self.__dict__`, and failing to find it there, the interpreter then follows the method resolution order of `USA` (`USA`, `A`, `B`, `object` as shown in the output) to find the `change_to_4` attribute in the first base class that has it defined.

Excerpt from the documentation of [Custom classes](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#custom-classes):

> Class attribute references are translated to lookups in this
> dictionary, e.g., `C.x` is translated to `C.__dict__["x"]` (although there
> are a number of hooks which allow for other means of locating
> attributes). When the attribute name is not found there, the attribute
> search continues in the base classes. This search of the base classes
> uses the C3 method resolution order which behaves correctly even in
> the presence of ‘diamond’ inheritance structures where there are
> multiple inheritance paths leading back to a common ancestor.

In this case, `A` is the first base class of `USA` that defines `change_to_4`, so `self.change_to_4()` gets translated to `A.change_to_4(self)`, resulting in `self.x = 4` getting executed.

That the call `self.change_to_4()` is made from a method in `B` does not change the fact that `A` comes before `B` in the method resolution order of a `USA` instance.